# Riddle: Waves and bristles, can you guess who am I?

Tags: riddle

Waves it's got,
but sea it's not.

Bristles it bears,
and it's no hog, I swear!

Comment: Short riddles often allow good interpretations and answers that were not intended, as is happening here. If there is some reason (beyond "that wasn't what I was thinking of") why the existing answers do not solve this riddle, it's not apparent at all what part of the riddle actually invalidates those responses. Because it seems they should be at least as valid as any other answer you might have in mind, this is "too broad"—you need to update the riddle to make sure invalid responses are demonstrably invalid.

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> A sonic toothbrush?
>
>  [image]
>  (really, it's a thing! even though it sounds like something from Doctor Who)

Waves it's got, but sea it's not.

> Sound travels in waves, and a sonic toothbrush emits sound waves.

Bristles it bears, and it's no hog, I swear!

> A sonic toothbrush still has traditional bristles.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it is:

> Sound ?

As,

> It travel in form of waves i.e. sound waves.

And

> Bristle is used to denote
>
>  [image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> Hair

because

> hair can be described as having waves

and

> hair can 'bear bristles' when it is being combed by a brush

Answer (score 1):

Some kind of

> hairy worm. It makes waves as it squirms, and the hairs are the bristles.

Answer (score 1):

Is it

> a broom?

Waves it's got, but sea it's not.

> Broom waves. There are several meanings to this, depending on your location.

Bristles it bears, and it's no hog, I swear!

> Brooms have bristles

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are

> Wheat/grain

Waves it's got, but sea it's not.

> Like in the song America the Beautiful: "Amber waves of grain", referring to wheat fields

Bristles it bears, and it's no hog, I swear!

> The 'beard' is the bristly material that protects the wheat kernel

Answer (score 1):

How about a

> [Oak processionary caterpillar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oak_processionary)

Waves it's got, but sea it's not.

> Caterpillars move in a wavy motion. Also, the processions on trees may look wavy.

Bristles it bears, and it's no hog

> The caterpillar has large bristly hairs (setae). A caterpillar is not a hog. <sup>[citation needed]</sup>

I swear!

> The hairs, that can become airborne, are known to cause extreme skin irritation because they contain a poisonous substance. Having an inflamed skin is certainly cause for swearing.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a

> Hedgehog

Bristles it bears, and it's no hog, I swear!

> Their spines could be thought of as bristles; and the hog draws attention to animals

Waves it's got, but sea it's not.

> I always wave to hedgehogs in my garden when I see them; and I'm taking the sea and see as not a play on words!!

Answer (score 0):

My Guess

> The branch of a tree, most likely a pine tee.

Waves it's got, but sea it's not.

> Branches seem to wave in the wind.

Bristles it bears, and it's no hog, I swear!

> Pine trees have bristles or pines on them.